# AJAX connecting to db with php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

I have never used ajax before and am trying to fully understand this example which is similar to what I want to do.  Here are my questions in regard to the sample code.

1. Do I need to include some sort of ajax header script to use it???
2. What does this part do in the html file:

   - `xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);`
   - `xmlhttp.send();`
3. This is where I have the biggest issue.  What is q?  Is it the vaule ex:1, 2,3 etc.??

   - `$q=$_GET["q"];`

Here is the html file....

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php file called getuser.php...

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'peter', 'abc123');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ajax_demo", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. It's a standard spec in EMCAScript.
2. That particular line of code opens a `GET` request to the `getuser.php` file, passing the GET parameter `q` as the value of `str` in your JS.
3. In that particular instance, $q is being set to the value of the `GET` value of `q`.

In a nutshell, your JS calls a PHP script to execute itself while passing a variable to (ostensibly) modify the results of the script.

If you don't understand `GET` and `POST` variables, I reccomend reading *at least* [the PHP manual's page on the `$_GET` array](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), or [a more general overview of `GET` and `POST` variables](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/variables2.php).

Comment: Thank you.  So 'q' is whatever value 'str' is?? So q and str could be 1,2,3,4,5 for example??

Comment: In this particular script, `str` would be equivalent to the currently set form item's `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This opens the file, and then sends the url to getuser.php. Basics :P

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
```

This is is what the ajax file sent to your getuser.php file. This shouldn't be a "security" variable because get is easy to hack. If it needs to be, try using post.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Thank you.  I do have further questions.  So what would be an example of a value of 'q'?  Is q whatever value 'str' is??

Comment: q will be whatever str is equal to.